# View transaction data in data table shiny app R

Tags: r, transactions, dataset, shiny

How can i display transaction dataset in table using Shiny? Im using the Groceries dataset from arules library. I want to display the data like this:

```
transactionID  items     
1              citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups                  
2              tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee                   
3              whole milk                
4              pip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese,meat spreads                 
5              other vegetables,whole milk,condensed milk,long life bakery product
```

here what i try to do but did not work

```
library(shiny)
library(arules)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("tableOutput")
    )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$tableOutput <- renderDataTable({
    dataset <- data(Groceries)
    transDat <- as(Groceries, "transactions")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: The reason it does not work in shiny is because transDat is not a data frame or matrix. I am unfamiliar with arules so not sure how to convert but that should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any way to convert the Groceries data into data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shiny does not register your transDat as a data frame. I have not worked with Groceries before so double check the transactionID and item sources, but potentially something like this:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    mainPanel(dataTableOutput("tableOutput"))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$tableOutput <- renderDataTable({

        # Load in Groceries and convert into a list
        data(Groceries)
        groceries <- as(Groceries, "list")

        # Collapse so each element in item list becomes one row in data frame
        items <- c()
        for (i in 1:length(groceries)){
            items <- c(items, paste(groceries[[i]], collapse=", ")  )
        }
        df <- data.frame("transactionInfo"=c(1:length(items)), "items"=items)
    })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

*Probably a simpler way to do that but this works*

Comment: Thank you. This works very well. I appreciate your help.